# Relations in Room database

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

Hello guys I've posts in my app each post can contain comments and replies on those comments.

I'm showing the last comment that's been written on the post (if it has any) and showing two replies that've been written on that comment (it it has any).

The problem is when I'm storing them in Room I want to store each of the posts, comments and replies in a separate table I added foreign keys in my database schema but the problem is happening when I want to retrieve them using RxJava I ran into callback hell and it's not even working.

```
dataManager.getPostsFromDatabase().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { it ->
                Log.d("yyyyyyyy", "posts size ${it.size}")
                it.forEach { postData ->
                    Log.d("yyyyyyyy", "post id ${postData.id}")
                    dataManager.getCommentFromDatabase(postData.id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe { comment ->
                                Log.d("yyyyyyyy", "post comment id ${comment.id}")
                                postData.last_comment = comment
                                dataManager.getRepliesFromDatabase(comment.id).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                        .subscribe { replies ->
                                            Log.d("yyyyyyyy", "replies count ${replies.size}")
                                            postData.last_comment?.replies = replies

                                        }

                            }
                    list.add(postData)
                }
            }
```

Any ideas to do that?

Comment: how did you annotate the POJO's in question?

Comment: That the post POKO @Entity(tableName = "posts")

Comment: and that's the comment @Entity(foreignKeys = (arrayOf(ForeignKey(entity = PostData::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["post_id"], onDelete = CASCADE, onUpdate = CASCADE))), tableName = "comments")

Comment: This is the reply @Entity(tableName = "replies", foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = CommentData::class, parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["parent_id"], onDelete = CASCADE, onUpdate = CASCADE)])